# Setting UTC Timezone is not working in Android

Tags: android, timezone, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert millisecond time value to UTC 12 hour format using following code:

```
    public void updateDateAndTimeForMumbai(String value) {
            SimpleDateFormat outputTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");
SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date.
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            try {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(value));
                Log.i("Scheduled date: " + outputDateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
                Log.i("Scheduled time: " + outputTimeFormatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
                Log.i("Scheduled time Am/Pm: " + new SimpleDateFormat("aa").format(calendar.getTime()));

            } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
                //do nothing and leave all fields as is

            }

        }
```

**Here value = "1479633900000"**

```
Output is: 
Scheduled date: 20/11/2016
Scheduled time: 2:55
Scheduled time Am/Pm: AM

What I want is:
Scheduled date: 20/11/2016
Scheduled time: 9:25
Scheduled time Am/Pm: AM
```

I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly use DateFormat.setTimeZone() to print the Date in the desired timezone.

```
outputDateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Call this after you do :

```
SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

If the time you are receiving from server is not UTC time, then you shouldn't set your Calendar instance to UTC. but just directly set your Calendar time.
Remove

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

And call

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Here is how should look your final code :

```
public void updateDateAndTimeForMumbai(String value) {
            SimpleDateFormat outputTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");
            outputTimeFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            outputDateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date.
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            try {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(value));
                Log.i("Scheduled date: " + outputDateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
                Log.i("Scheduled time: " + outputTimeFormatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
                Log.i("Scheduled time Am/Pm: " + new SimpleDateFormat("aa").format(calendar.getTime()));

            } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
                //do nothing and leave all fields as is

            }

        }
```

Comment: It does not work , I am still getting the same result